# Get full SKU for configurable products with custom options in transactional emails

Tags: configurable-product, ce-1.7.0.2, custom-options, email-templates, transactional-mail

I try to get the full SKU for configurable products with custom options in transactional emails. By default this works great in the shopping cart.

For example, I have a configurable product with SKU 'Test product' and one custom option with the SKU '`CUSTOMOPT1`'. The associated simple product has SKU '`Test product - Color 1`.

In the shopping cart the SKU is ok: '`Test product - Color 1-CUSTOMOPT1`'. Unfortunately, in the transactional emails the SKU is '`Test product - Color 1`' (without the SKU of the selected custom option).

How I can get the full SKU (just like in shopping cart) in the transactional emails?

Answer (score 0):

When Magento converts the quote object to the order object it does not save the configurable products SKU in the `sales_flat_order_item` table, so you can not get the configurable product SKU from there.

Whenever Magento saves configurable products into order objects, it saves two rows.

1. One row:

   configurable product id / no parent product Item / child sku with custom option sku
2. Another

   simple product id / parent product item / child  product sku

When Magento sends mails, it calls the following code

```
 $_items=$_order->getItemsCollection();

<?php foreach ($_items as $_item): ?>
        <?php if ($_item->getParentItem()) continue; ?>

...

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So it is not possible to get the correct format in the transactional emails?

Comment: Try to load product by product id.....

Comment: or you can get a product sku from the product id without a full load